# Program never ends

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not sure what's going on, but in the console I have a red 'stop' square that i can click to stop my program from running (Eclipse IDE) and my program is just running and the square stays red..?

EDIT:

my maze:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WSOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOW
WWOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOW
WWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOW
WOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWW
WOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOWWWWOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOWWWWWWWWWOWWWWW
WOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWOOOOOWW
WOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOW
WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWOOW
WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOW
WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWFW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

EDIT: here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.awt.Point;

public class MazeExplorer {
    static Point startPoint = new Point();
    static Point finishPoint = new Point();
    final static int mazeHeight = 12;
    final static int mazeWidth = 58;
    static char[][] mazePoints = new char[mazeHeight][mazeWidth];
    Stack<Point> pointsNotTraversed = new Stack<Point>();
    Point pt = new Point();
    static HashSet<Point> previousLocations = new HashSet<Point>();
    static Stack<Point> nextPoints = new Stack<Point>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        System.out.println("Please enter the file name of your Maze");
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        File f = new File(console.nextLine());
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

        if(!sc.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println("Sorry, please enter a file name with the extension, that contains a maze!");
        }
        System.out.println("So, you want to know if your maze is solvable.....?");

        for (int row = 0; row < mazeHeight && sc.hasNext(); row++) {
            final String mazeRow = sc.next(); //Get the next row from the scanner.
            mazePoints[row] = mazeRow.toCharArray(); //Convert the row into a char[].
        }
            //identify the finish point
        for(int i = 0; i < mazeHeight; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<mazeWidth; j++){
                if(mazePoints[i][j] == 'F'){
                    finishPoint = new Point(i, j);
                }       
            }
        }
        // Identify the start point
       for(int i = 0; i< mazeHeight; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j < mazeWidth; j++){
               if(mazePoints[i][j] == 'S'){
                 startPoint = new Point(i , j);
               }
           }
       }
       isTraversable(startPoint);    
    }
        public static  boolean isTraversable(Point current){
            boolean isSolvable = false;
            nextPoints.push(current);

            do {


                if(current.y < 11) {
                    if((mazePoints[current.y + 1][current.x] != ' ') && (mazePoints[current.y + 1][current.x] != 'W') ){ // below direction
                    nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y + 1, current.x));
                    mazePoints[current.y + 1][current.x] = ' ';        
                    isTraversable(nextPoints.pop());    

                }
                }
                if(current.y > 0){


                if (mazePoints[current.y - 1][current.x] != ' ' && mazePoints[current.y - 1][current.x] != 'W' ){ //up dir
                   nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y - 1, current.x));
                    mazePoints[current.y - 1][current.x] = ' ';  //'X' marks where you've already been
                   isTraversable(nextPoints.pop());     

                }
                }
                if(current.x < 57){
                if(mazePoints[current.y][current.x + 1] != ' ' && mazePoints[current.y][current.x + 1] != 'W'){ // to the right
                    nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y, current.x + 1));
                    mazePoints[current.y][current.x + 1] = ' ';
                    isTraversable(nextPoints.pop());    

                }
                }
                if(current.x > 0){


                if(mazePoints[current.y][current.x - 1] != ' ' && mazePoints[current.y][current.x - 1] != 'W') { // to the left
                    nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y, current.x - 1));
                    mazePoints[current.y][current.x - 1] = ' ';     
                    isTraversable(nextPoints.pop());    

                }
                }
                if(current.equals(finishPoint)){
                    isSolvable = true;
                    System.out.println("MAZE IS SOLVABLE, YAHOOOOOO!!!!");
                }




            } while(!current.equals('F') && !nextPoints.isEmpty());    


            return isSolvable;          
        }
}
```

Comment: Very, very vague. If you think it's because of your code, kindly post your code here. If it persists with any code, then it's best to go to SuperUser for this, not SO.

Comment: Well, do you have some sort of infinite loop? What is your program?

Comment: You've pasted a random snippet of code and stated that your program doesn't exit. This is not enough information.

Comment: @JasonC I have edited to all of my code for the entire program, I am trying to traverse a maze and return true/false if it is traversable or not

Comment: Eclipse has a great debugger. Use it. Run your program in the debugger, and when it hangs, pause it. It will show you exactly what line its stuck on, and you can step through and see what it's doing.

Comment: @JasonC nothing happened...it just still goes infinitely..

Comment: Here's my take on your program...You call isTraversable with the startPoint as the parameter. Great. You examine a series of if statements...you push a new point on the stack then re-call isTraversable() and pop one off the stack. Each if statement pushes one point on and pops one point off. How will the stack ever be empty this way?

Comment: @Solace I am recalling isTraversable with the value of pop()...should I be using peek()?

Comment: I'm not sure. I did the maze with stacks project in my prog class, but I didn't do it recursively. The general idea what that...for every position, there are three possibilities. We can either go up, go right, or go down. We choose one direction to always traverse in. For example, if we were in a position where we could go in all three directions...we would move right, and push the above position and below position on the stack. (They will be examined later with the same algorithm. Is your maze solvable?

Comment: The one I'm testing is solvable, I also have one to test that isn't.....can we go into chat and work on it?

Comment: Sure why not. I always enjoy a challenge. My curfew is in 35 minutes though

Comment: oops not enough rep to chat...

Comment: Alright. Is recursion a requirement? And are you certain your function header is correct? I can imagine this being done with a void recursive function

Comment: recursion isn't required, function header?

Comment: I'll try to come up with something

Comment: Since you told me recursion isn't a requirement, I wrote this non-recursively. Please be aware that I didn't test this code. There might be bugs. Also your canGoRight,Up,Down methods needs to account for dead ends (instead of just bounds issues).

Comment: @bazookyelmo Whether you accept my answer or someone else's, it is important to accept answers on StackOverflow. that is as important as asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested before, you just need to reconfigure your recursive method. I took the liberty of doing this but if you ever want to learn how to program you'll want to try and solve problems like these on your own. Or try to understand the logic of your solution before you start coding.

Your main problem is that you don't know what direction you want to go in with the method before you just jumped in and that was causing all sorts of errors with different things not being compatible with each other.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.awt.Point;

public class TestCode {
    static Point startPoint = new Point();
    static Point finishPoint = new Point();
    final static int mazeHeight = 12;
    final static int mazeWidth = 58;
    static char[][] mazePoints = new char[mazeHeight][mazeWidth];
    Stack<Point> pointsNotTraversed = new Stack<Point>();
    Point pt = new Point();
    static HashSet<Point> previousLocations = new HashSet<Point>();
    static Stack<Point> nextPoints = new Stack<Point>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    System.out.println("Please enter the file name of your Maze");
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    File f = new File(console.nextLine());
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

    if(!sc.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println("Sorry, please enter a file name with the extension, that contains a maze!");
    }
    System.out.println("So, you want to know if your maze is solvable.....?");

    for (int row = 0; row < mazeHeight && sc.hasNext(); row++) {
        final String mazeRow = sc.next(); //Get the next row from the scanner.
        mazePoints[row] = mazeRow.toCharArray(); //Convert the row into a char[].
    }
        //identify the finish point
    for(int i = 0; i < mazeHeight; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<mazeWidth; j++){
            if(mazePoints[i][j] == 'F'){
                finishPoint = new Point(i, j);
            }       
        }
    }
    // Identify the start point
   for(int i = 0; i< mazeHeight; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < mazeWidth; j++){
           if(mazePoints[i][j] == 'S'){
             startPoint = new Point(i , j);
           }
       }
   }
   System.out.println(isTraversable(startPoint));    
}
    public static  boolean isTraversable(Point current){

        mazePoints[current.x][current.y] = ' ';

        if(current.y < 56 && current.y > 0 && current.x > 0 && current.x < 11){
            if (mazePoints[current.x - 1][current.y] == 'O'){ // Up dir
                Point upPoint = new Point(current.x-1, current.y);
                nextPoints.push(upPoint);
            }

            if(mazePoints[current.x+1][current.y] == 'O'){ // Down dir
                Point downPoint = new Point(current.x+1, current.y);
                nextPoints.push(downPoint);
            }

            if(mazePoints[current.x][current.y + 1] == 'O'){ // to the right
                Point rightPoint = new Point(current.x, current.y+1);
                nextPoints.push(rightPoint);
            }

            if(mazePoints[current.x][current.y - 1] == 'O'){ // to the left
                Point leftPoint = new Point(current.x, current.y-1);
                nextPoints.push(leftPoint);
            }

            if(mazePoints[current.x - 1][current.y] == 'F' ||
               mazePoints[current.x + 1][current.y] == 'F' ||
               mazePoints[current.x][current.y - 1] == 'F' ||
               mazePoints[current.x][current.y + 1] == 'F'){
                System.out.println("MAZE IS SOLVABLE, YAHOOOOOO!!!!");
                return true;
            }

        }
        if(nextPoints.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            current = nextPoints.pop();
        }

        return(isTraversable(current));

    }
}
```

With the maze input:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WSOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOW
WWOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOW
WWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOW
WOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWW
WOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOWWWWOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOWWWWWWWWWOWWWWW
WOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWOOOOOWW
WOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOW
WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWOOW
WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOW
WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOFW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Yields the following output:

```
So, you want to know if your maze is solvable.....?
MAZE IS SOLVABLE, YAHOOOOOO!!!!
true
```

I imported the file a different way, but you can change that back to whatever method you use previously.

Comment: This should be called in the main method with the start point passed in?

Comment: yes. I did that in a print statement `System.out.println(isTraversable(startPoint));`

Comment: That will print "true" as well as the "yahoooo" line you wrote in the method.

Comment: hmm, that's weird...keep getting false for the solvable maze..

Comment: I don't. I'll add the whole program. for clarity.

Comment: @bazookyelmo You probably changed something in the body of the program. The whole project was edited in the answer for clarity.

Comment: why is file args[0] ?

Comment: @bazookyelmo I explained that at the very bottom. I used a different way of getting the file. Just change it back to what you had. I updated it to reflect the 4 lines of code you originally had as well.

Comment: This all makes perfect sense, but my result is still false?

Comment: @bazookyelmo Check your maze file. I'm running the code that is posted above. It works and it prints out true for me. Code never lies, so check the input file and make sure it hasn't been modified.

Comment: I'm 99% sure these are the same mazes, but this one I'm posting as an EDIT in my question returns false....the one you have posted returns true...?

Answer (score 1):

Might be that you've started multiple programs and you have the "Show Console When Standard Output Changes" Not sure, but that explains one scenario. If you start task manager and find the program there you could try terminating it that way.

Comment: Tried that, still goes infinitely....

Comment: Apologies, but a guess does not an answer make. This is better suited as a comment instead.

Comment: I would have made this a comment if I had enough rep :) A long shot but it might have been the answer!

Comment: @xtré its alright, you taught me something new still!!

Answer (score 0):

If it's stuck running and never completes you could try running your program in the Eclipse debugger, without any breakpoints. 
Open the Debug tab (Open in from Window > Show View > Debug), suspend the thread by right clicking 'Thread [main] (Running)' and selecting 'Suspend'.
Then work your way up from the bottom of the stack, hopefully this will narrow it down enough for you to find where it blocks.

Comment: already tried, no avail

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;


public class test5 {

private int numRows;
private int numCols;

public test5(){
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter number of rows: ");
 numRows = input.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter number of cols: ");
 numCols = input.nextInt();

 Stack<Point>stack = new Stack<Point>();
 stack.push(new Point(0,0));


 while(!stack.isEmpty()){

     if(currentPath(stack.pop(),stack)){
         System.out.println("Maze is solvable");
     }



 }

}

public static void main(String[]args){

    new test5();

}

private boolean currentPath(Point point, Stack<Point>stack){
    int currentRow = point.getRow();
    int currentCol = point.getCol();

    while(currentRow!=numRows-1 || currentCol!=numCols-1){
        boolean canGoRight = canGoRight(currentRow,currentCol);
        boolean canGoUp = canGoUp(currentRow,currentCol);
        boolean canGoDown = canGoDown(currentRow,currentCol);

        if(canGoRight){
            if(canGoUp){
                stack.push(new Point(currentRow-1,currentCol));
            }
            if(canGoDown){
                stack.push(new Point(currentRow+1,currentCol));
            }
            currentCol = currentCol+1;
        }
        else{
            if(canGoUp){
                if(canGoDown){
                    stack.push(new Point(currentRow+1,currentCol));

                }
                currentRow = currentRow-1;

            }
            else if(canGoDown){
                currentRow = currentRow+1;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

        }
    }

    return true;
}



private  boolean canGoUp(int row, int col){
    return row-1>=0; 
}

private  boolean canGoRight(int row, int col){
    return col+1<numCols;
}

private  boolean canGoDown(int row, int col){
    return row+1<numRows;
}

class Point{
    private int row;
    private int col;

    public Point(int row, int col){
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    public int getRow(){
        return row;
    }

    public int getCol(){
        return col;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: might be a dumb question...but where does my maze file go?

Comment: If you're using eclipse, you can put it in the project folder.