# Maze solving using recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

homework question here, been coding this for hours and hours and hours but I cant seem to get the correct output so I was hoping for some help from you guys.

My code is:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

 public class Maze {

    private int[][] grid;
    private final int TRIED = 2;
    private final int PATH = 3;

    public Maze(String fileName) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String s;
        String [] aux= new String [2];
        int x=0; 

        aux=in.readLine().split("\\s*[, .]\\s*");
        int dimensao=Integer.parseInt(aux[0]);
        String [][] gridString= new String [dimensao][dimensao];
        grid= new int[dimensao][dimensao];

         while ((s=in.readLine())!=null){
            gridString [x]=s.split("\\s*[, .]\\s*");
            x++;
        }

        for (int i=0;i<gridString.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<gridString[0].length;j++){
                switch (gridString[i][j]) {
                    case "true":
                        grid[i][j]=1;
                        break;
                    case "false":
                        grid[i][j]=0;
                        break;
                }
            } 
            }
    }
    public boolean traverse(int row, int column) {
        boolean done = false;
        if (valid(row, column)) {
            grid[row][column] = TRIED; // this cell has been tried
            if (row==grid.length-1)
                done = true; // the maze is solved
             else {
                done = traverse(row + 1, column); // down
                if (!done) 
                    done = traverse(row, column + 1); // right
                if (!done) 
                    done = traverse(row - 1, column); // up
                if (!done) 
                    done = traverse(row, column - 1); // left
            }
            if (done) // this location is part of the final path
                grid[row][column] = PATH;

        }
        return done;
    }

    private boolean valid(int row, int column) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (row >= 0 && row < grid.length
                && column >= 0 && column < grid[row].length) // check if cell is not blocked and not previously tried
        {
            if (grid[row][column] == 1) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public String toString (){
        String result = "\n";
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < grid[0].length; column++) {
                result += grid[row][column] + "";
            }
            result += "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }
    public String [][]transformMatrix (int [][]array ){
        String [][] matrizChar= new String [array.length][array[0].length];
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<array[0].length;j++){
            if (array[i][j]==1)
                matrizChar[i][j]="*";
            else matrizChar[i][j]="-";
            }
             return matrizChar;   

    } 

}
```

And the other class is:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        {
            Maze labyrinth = new Maze("rede.txt");
            System.out.println(labyrinth);
            boolean done=labyrinth.traverse(0, 0);
            if (labyrinth.traverse(0, 0)) {
                System.out.println("The maze was successfully traversed!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("There is no possible path.");
            }

            System.out.println(labyrinth);

        }
    }
}
```

The text input I am using is

5

true, false, true, false, false

true, false, true, true, true

false, false, false, false, true

true, true, false, true, true

false, false, false, true, false

And it generates the array:

1 0 1 0 0

1 0 1 1 1

0 0 0 0 1

0 0 0 1 0

0 0 0 1 0

Because it translates the input text file to an integer array.

Now my problem is that it solves the maze like this

2 0 1 0 0

2 0 1 1 1

0 0 0 0 1

1 1 0 1 1

0 0 0 1 0

When it should solve it like this

2 0 3 0 0

2 0 3 3 3

0 0 0 0 3

1 1 0 3 3

0 0 0 3 0

It also says that the maze has no solution so I'm guessing the problem relies on the "traverse" method but I sincerely cant find out where the error is.
Would really appreciate help!

Comment: Have you tried debugger yet? Tool like eclipse debugger really helps a lot

Comment: I did, hours of that. The only thing I can think of is that it doesnt find solutions if there is a 0 on the first line before the correct path. But I have no idea how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is from the return statement inside the `traverse()` method. Walking through this:

- When (0,0) valid(row,column) is true.
- Sets equal to 2, moves down one and calls traverse(1,0).
- when (1,0) valid(row, column) is true
- Sets equal to 2, moves down one and calls traverse(2,0).
- when (2,0) valid(row,column) is false
- returns done (ie false)
- All other if statements return false (surrounding values are not valid)
- program ends.

The program

```
public boolean traverse(int row, int column) {
            boolean done = false;
            if (valid(row, column)) {
                grid[row][column] = TRIED; // this cell has been tried
                if (row==grid.length-1)
                    done = true; // the maze is solved
                 else {
                    done = traverse(row + 1, column); // not valid
                    if (!done) 
                        done = traverse(row, column + 1); // not valid
                    if (!done) 
                        done = traverse(row - 1, column); // not valid
                    if (!done) 
                        done = traverse(row, column - 1); // not valid
                }
                if (done) // this location is part of the final path
                    grid[row][column] = PATH;

            }
            return done;  
        }
```

**Also Noteworthy**

Your starting position (0, 0) does not have a legal path to the end, so naturally you're going to get that as an answer. If you want to find the legal path, then either traverse all possible starting points or make the start point somewhere on the actual completable path.

[image: Impossible Maze]

Comment: Yes that is what I found out using the debugger, do you have any pointers on how to fix it?

Comment: I acutally solved a similar maze issue recently [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240545/program-never-ends). It's a different approach, but it doesn't get hung up on things like this. It is a recursive approach which moves in all directions from the start location until it finds a path. You may want a mixture of the two approaches.

Comment: @user3343824 In short, this would fail in real life just the same. Your "starting point" doesn't HAVE a path to the end point, so there isn't a solution. If you want to find the right path you'll want to make the start point somewhere on the actual legal path.

Comment: I'm trying to create a cycle that runs through every column and goes from there, but I am just failing miserably

Comment: Well then you are close. The problem is that you don't continue if you reach a square with a value of 0. This shouldn't stop your program, it should just merely not consider it a path. Perhaps modify the validate() method to allow for anything within the bounds of the grid.

Comment: Did a new method with a while that would traverse all columns and now it seems to work!

Comment: @user3343824 excellent! I've been looking over it myself. Haven't figured how to fix this with the current setup.